# How to calculate Silhouette Score of the scipy's fcluster using scikit-learn silhouette score?

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering

I am using scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage as a clustering algorithm and pass the result linkage matrix to [scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster.html), to get the flattened clusters, for various thresholds.

I would like to calculate the Silhouette score of the results and compare them to choose the best threshold and prefer not to implement it on my own but use scikit-learn's [sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html). 
How can I rearrange my clustering results as an input to sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score?

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to.

Results of fcluster can directly be fed into silhouette_score.

```
distmatrix1 = scipy.spatial.distance.squareform(distmatrix + distmatrix.T)
ddgm = scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage(distmatrix1, method="average")
nodes = scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster(ddgm, 4, criterion="maxclust")
metrics.silhouette_score(distmatrix + distmatrix.T , nodes, metric='euclidean')
```

Comment: Just to add a little detail for anyone coming to this problem as I did, being a little confused by the addition going on in this answer: The `distmatrix + distmatrix.T` portion is just your X (the features used to generate the columns) and the `nodes` is your y (the labels of the clusters). You can just reference these directly out of your dataframe, rather than as separate objects.