# calculate Silhouette Score of the scipy's fcluster using scikit-learn silhouette score

Tags: scipy, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, silhouette

I am  doing hierarchy clustering using scipy.cluster followed by fcluster under different cutoff. 
I want to also use scikit's  silhouette_score.
I see the post [How to calculate Silhouette Score of the scipy's fcluster using scikit-learn silhouette score?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27875056/how-to-calculate-silhouette-score-of-the-scipys-fcluster-using-scikit-learn-sil)
However, i got error "too many boolean indices"??

My codes is following:

```
import fastcluster
from sklearn import metrics
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy as hac


Temps=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
Distance=[]
#read the Distance obtained as a list then
Distances=np.array(Distances)
Z=fastcluster.linkage(Distances, "complete", "euclidean")
for Cutoff in Temps:
    results=hac.fcluster(Z,Cutoff,'distance')
    metrics.silhouette_score(Distances, results, metric="euclidean")
```

The error report was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Clustering_2.py", line 93, in <module>
    main(argv)
  File "Clustering_2.py", line 69, in main
    silscore=metrics.silhouette_score(Distances, results,metric='euclidean')
  File "/home/wangz18/site-packages2/sklearn/metrics/cluster/unsupervised.py", line 93, in silhouette_score
    return np.mean(silhouette_samples(X, labels, metric=metric, **kwds))
  File "/home/wangz18/site-packages2/sklearn/metrics/cluster/unsupervised.py", line 157, in silhouette_samples
    for i in range(n)])
  File "/home/wangz18/site-packages2/sklearn/metrics/cluster/unsupervised.py", line 187, in _intra_cluster_distance
    a = np.mean(distances_row[mask])
ValueError: too many boolean indices
```

what's the problem? please advise. Thanks

Comment: this code sample is incomplete, can you add the imports for `fastcluster` and `hac` and the definition of `Distances` and `Cutoff`?

Comment: also add the traceback for too many boolean indices, please!

Comment: The changes has been made asked. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you have the right input to `silhouette_score`? According to the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html), the first argument X needs to be *X : array [n_samples_a, n_samples_a] if metric == “precomputed”, or, [n_samples_a, n_features] otherwise* . Which I take to mean that unless you set `metric` to “precomputed” it expects a matrix of features, not distances.

Comment: Distances is a condensed distance matrix

Comment: yes, that's what I mean. If you look at the docs, I don't think it expects you to put in a distance matrix but your original featurematrix:  [n_samples_a, n_features]

Comment: Thanks! i think should do one more step  Dicts =squareform(Distances), then use the Dicts for metrics.silhouette_score

Comment: I'm not familiar with what squareform does, but looks like that will give you yet another distance matrix. My understanding would be that just changing your code to `metrics.silhouette_score(Distances, results, metric="precomputed")` should get rid of [the|an] error. Cf docs: *If X is the distance array itself, use metric="precomputed"*

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question, and please check:

1. **Distance** is N*N, N is the number of samples
2. **results** is N, and the value is the class of cluster
3. The number of cluster should be > 1

If #1 and #2 are correct, them it should be correct.